I recently graduated with a University Bachelor Degree in Computer Engineering, and I am thinking about becoming a Latin teacher. What should I do?
Per my previous question, I recently graduated with a University Bachelor Degree in Computer Engineering from the University of Osijek. However, I don't want to be a programmer any more. Merely getting a Bachelor degree in Computer Engineering cost me my mental health. I got a psychotic disorder while studying an undergraduate program in Computer Engineering, and I guess that working as a programmer is even more stressful than studying it.
I was thinking about getting a Bachelor degree in the Latin language from the University of Zadar, and starting a career as a Latin teacher. It's a double-major ("dvopredmetni studij"). I need to study something else with it, and I can choose to study Latin and Ancient Greek or Latin and Linguistics. While I do speak some Latin (I have published a few YouTube videos in Latin, the latest one is about the afterlife, and I am also active on Latin Language StackExchange), I don't speak a word of Ancient Greek. I find it rather awkward to enroll in a university program teaching a language that I don't speak a word of. As for linguistics, I need to study two foreign languages there, one of them being non-Indo-European, and I am a bit afraid of that. I know how bad it went to enroll in a course at a university teaching a programming language I had no previous knowledge of, and my guess is that studying a human language you have no knowledge of is even worse. Is my fear realistic?
My father suggests me to study Political Science at the University of Belgrade, because he happens to know a few people who work there. However, I am afraid that's not for me because of all those economics courses there. I took one economics courses while studying Computer Engineering (called "Ekonomika poduzeća"), and I barely got a passing score (a D) there. I am afraid that many of my courses would be like that if I study political science. Do you think my fear is realistic?
I have published a few papers about the names of places in Croatia, the latest one being "Etimologija Karašica", which I published in Valpovački Godišnjak and Regionalne Studije (an almanac for the Croatian national minority in and around Sopron). Many people in real life, including my information theory professors, have told me they think it is a rather high-quality paper, and that I should continue doing that.
What do you advise me to do?

A Latin teacher at what level: secondary school, university?

Keep in mind that the job prospects for a Latin degree are pretty slim. Generally, a fairly significant portion of people who get degrees in linguistics or languages don't end up with careers based on those concentrations. This will be especially true for Latin as it is a functionally dead language.

@Buffy I was considering a secondary school.

You are obviously passionate about Latin and teaching, and ideally, you'd follow your passion. Still, another full Bachelor's degree is a large investment of time and effort.
Have you considered other options besides the degree programs you mentioned? At least in the UK, there are 1-1.5 year conversion courses to teaching for those with a Bachelor's degree. Due to a lack of teachers, there are even shorter options with part-time teaching. I don't know what is available in your case, but it can be worth checking places not just in Croatia but in other EU countries as well.
If possible, you might want to try some teaching (maybe computer science?) before embarking upon another degree.
